# Pressing enter submits form but breaks accessibility

Tags: jquery, forms, accessibility

I have an HTML form. I'm intercepting the activation of the submit button as I need to run some javascript rather than normal form submission.

I added javascript so that both pressing enter and clicking the submit button activates the form (I think this is normal practice). However this breaks accessibility. When the user tabs to another button or link outside the form and then presses enter, the button that has focus aught to activate. However it doesnt - the form button gets activated instead. What is the standard way of dealing with this (I get the feeling I'm missing something fundamental here)?

Simplified version of what I'm using to capture hitting enter (jQuery)....

```
    $("form").bind("keydown", function(e){
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.currentTarget.blur();
                $("button").click();
                return false;
            }
         });
```

Comment: I would drop that way completely, and overrun `onSubmit()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intercept the `submit()` action instead, and use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) to cancel it immediately:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // more code
});
```